# ExifInterface Latitude/Longitude return null - Android

Tags: java, android, coordinates, exif

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm developing a really simple app for Android that's suppose to get a picture from gallery, displays it and show its coordinates in a `TextView` (latitude and longitude).
I have an `ExifInterface` object, but the tags (such as `TAG_GPS_LATITUDE` and `TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE`) return `null`.
I've tried many different solutions found on StackOverflow but none of them worked, so I thought of making a new question showing my code.

MainActivity.java:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Uri imgUri;
    String realPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                openGallery(arg0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void openGallery(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            imgUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
            realPath = getRealPathFromURI(this, imgUri);
            try {
                ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(realPath);
                textView.append("Latitude: " + ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE) + " Longitude: " + ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not every jpg with exif header has location tags.

Comment: @greenapps I know, but the image I'm using to check has location tags. It shows the latitude and longitude in another app I got from PlayStore. Can you help me out?

Comment: Tell the value for imgUri.toString(). And of realPath please.

Comment: Why dont you put a Toast() in that catch blok to inform the user and yourself in case something goes wrong?

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for answering. The realPath returns something like: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_345678_4567.jpg, and imgUri.toString() returns: content://media/external/images/media/62248. The realPath is the same as it shows in the other app that also shows the correct coordinates. Thank you.